# Wrap a character with "

Tags: r, character, word-wrap

I'm trying to find function which returns `x` when I put `x`.

What I'm expecting is:

```r
>function(x)
[1] "x"
```

I searched over for this "wrapping" function to no avail.

Comment: r u looking for `f <- function(x) as.character(match.call())[-1L]`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks. Exactly what I wanted. I can give a credit if you post it as an answer. Or I can erase this question if you want.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Need advice...When I try to make some kind of 'general' function, I always encounter that "match.call()" function. Do you think I really need to study 'advanced-r' by Hadley Wickham?

Comment: why don't you start with the help page for `match.call` first

Answer (score 1):

When you type:

```
x <- "a"
x
[1] "a"
```

... There is no "real" double quote in the result. The flanking double-quotes are produced by the implicit `print` function in the REPL loop (read-eval-print). So perhaps you are only asking for the `print` function?

If you really want three characters (two `"` and one `a`) then you will need to do this:

```
x <- "\"a\""
nchar(x)
[1] 3
```